# Builder Pattern with only one class

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm learning the Builder Pattern. I have a question, Why don't using a class (ex: MyCoffe)instead of 2 class (ex: MyCoffe, BuilderClass). Thanks you for reading.

```
package Creational.Builder;

public class MyCoffe {

        private String name;
        private int id;

        public MyCoffe(){

        }

        public MyCoffe setName(String newName){
            this.name  = newName;
            return this;
        }

        public MyCoffe setId(int newId){
            this.id = newId;
            return this;
        }

        public MyCoffe build(){
            return this;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return name + "/" + id;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            MyCoffe myCoffe = new MyCoffe().setName("HelloWorld").setId(9999);  
            System.out.println(myCoffe);

            System.out.println("Thanks for help!");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly *can* in some select situations, but one of the purposes of the builder pattern is to avoid having an *invalid instance* of a class. So unless it's valid for `MyCoffe` to not have a name or ID, you don't want an instance of it running around without a name or ID, like this:

```
MyCoffe invalid = new MyCoffe();
```

Also note that when the class is self-building like that, it's easy to forget to call the final `build` method (as, in fact, you did in your `main`), so the instance never gets validated.

Hence using a separate builder to hold the incomplete information before building the complete, valid instance.

In Java, it's not uncommon for the builder to be a static nested class:

```
public class MyCoffe {

    public static class Builder {
        private String name;
        private int id;

        public Builder() {
        }

        public Builder setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public MyCoffe build() {
            if (this.name == null) {
                throw new AppropriateException("'name' is required");
            }
            if (this.id == 0) { // Assumes 0 isn't a valid ID
                throw new AppropriateException("'id' is required");
            }
            return new MyCoffe(name, id);
        }
    }

    private String name;
    private int id;

    public MyCoffe(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name + "/" + id;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyCoffe myCoffe = new MyCoffe.Builder().setName("HelloWorld").setId(9999).build();
        System.out.println(myCoffe);

        System.out.println("Thanks for help!");
    }
}
```

Or if declaring the properties twice like that bothers you, `MyCoffe` can allow **private** incomplete instances, like this:

```
public class MyCoffe {

    public static class Builder {
        private MyCoffe instance;

        public Builder() {
            this.instance = new MyCoffe();
        }

        public Builder setName(String name) {
            this.instance.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setId(int id) {
            this.instance.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public MyCoffe build() {
            if (this.instance.name == null) {
                throw new AppropriateException("'name' is required");
            }
            if (this.instance.id == 0) { // Assumes 0 isn't a valid ID
                throw new AppropriateException("'id' is required");
            }
            return this.instance;
        }
    }

    private String name;
    private int id;

    private MyCoffe() {
    }

    public MyCoffe(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name + "/" + id;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyCoffe myCoffe = new MyCoffe.Builder().setName("HelloWorld").setId(9999).build();
        System.out.println(myCoffe);

        System.out.println("Thanks for help!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank @T.J. Crowder, i so begin. I 'm studying your help. But if make more Builder class, We must write double properties.

Comment: Recalling _Effective Java_ item 1, required fields should be asked for at the builder constructor. Always prefer compile time errors over runtime exceptions.

Comment: @MouseEvent: That applies to building `MyCoffe`, not `MyCoffe.Builder`. Builders are specifically for the case where the information required to build the end result varies sufficiently that a constructor or set of constructors with all the various permutations are not an effective choice.

Comment: @GeoWesley: You only end up declaring the fields twice, unless `MyCoffe` also has setters. But another choice is to have `MyCoffe` allow **private** invalid instances; I've added an example above. I probably wouldn't do that, but...

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, 
return new MyCoffe(name, id); 
In Builder class, it make seem un Builder Pattern(Sory my english)

Comment: @GeoWesley: That's just internal plumbing, which you can write any of several ways (two of which are shown above, only one of which uses `new MyCoffe(name, id)`). The point is the external (public) interface.